# Общее обстоятельство времени в сложносочиненном предложении

Tags: запятые, ссп

На каком основании  автор не считает  обстоятельство **«в этот миг»** общим второстепенным членом в приведенном предложении:

*– Я хочу выяснить, есть ли там призрак. – Мальчик подпрыгнул и попытался ухватиться за край гробницы.*

*– И ты не боишься? А что, если призрак тебя схватит?*

*– Днем? Днем призраки не выходят! – не очень уверенно сказал вундеркинд.*

***В этот миг крышка усыпальницы приподнялась, и за край ухватилась огромная ручища**.*

*– Все ушли? Ну и духотища здесь! – прозвучал низкий загробный голос.*

**Разная последовательность действий?**  Но это же восприятие со стороны, когда мы видим оба движения в один миг, вряд ли это могло повлиять на знаки.

1. Значит, есть еще причина, а какая?
2. Существуют ли какие-либо особенности **общего обстоятельства времени** в других примерах?
3. И можно ли так **перестроить предложение**, чтобы не ставить запятую?

Спасибо.

Comment: Может, следствие (которое произошло после "мига")? Миг — это как бы максимум где-то секунда.

Comment: Я как раз и думаю - вряд ли нужно высчитывать эти секунды. Скорее всего, точный смысловой фактор здесь не главный.

Comment: Или это, или кто-то не знал правило, которое далеко не самое известное (не всегда его в школах проходят).

Comment: Это же художественная литература (Д. Емец). у него всё правильно. Переделайте предложение, чтобы не было запятой, это будет шаг к решению. Я пока не знаю как.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что причина в том, что союз «и» означает здесь не одновременность, а последовательность действий.

У союза «и» есть такое значение:

> 2. Соединяет предложения, связанные друг с другом **временной последовательностью излагаемых событий**.
>
> *Мы простились еще раз, и лошади поскакали.* Пушкин, Выстрел.
> *Контракт был подписан, и Галактион принялся за работу.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Хлеб.
> *[Гречка] ловко вскочил в кузов, стукнул шоферу — и грузовик укатил.* Панова, Ясный берег.
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

*«Мы простились еще раз, и лошади поскакали»* — сначала простились, а потом лошади поскакали, а не одновременно: временная последовательность событий.

Я полагаю, что «и» тут по смыслу с некоторой точностью можно заменить на «затем»:
*«Мы простились еще раз, затем лошади поскакали».*

---

*«В этот миг крышка усыпальницы приподнялась, и за край ухватилась огромная ручища».*

Тут «и» точно так же означает временную последовательность событий: сначала *«крышка усыпальницы приподнялась»*, а затем *«за край ухватилась огромная ручища»*.

«В этот миг» указывает только на время первого действия, а второе действие уже происходит после того, как *«крышка усыпальницы приподнялась»*. Поэтому «в этот миг» не является общим обстоятельством времени.

---

Кроме того:

> МИГ, -а, м. Очень короткий промежуток времени; мгновение, момент...
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

Исходя из смысла слова «миг» — мгновение: вряд ли оба события могли в него уместиться, а более вероятно, что произошло *в миг* одно событие, а затем другое; и «миг» ко второму уже отношения не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, а свой ответ я добавлю чуть позже.

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже говорила,  вряд ли автор хотел  **точно следовать словарному значению** сочетания «в этот миг»  –  такие подробности обычно  не входят в  художественную задачу.  Здесь что-то другое,  связанное с **необходимостью паузы**,  и пока у  меня есть две версии.

**1.  Грамматическая версия** (связана со структурой предложения)

*В этот миг крышка усыпальницы приподнялась, и за **(её)** край  ухватилась огромная ручища.*

Здесь пропущено местоимение, но оно подразумевается – возможно, это препятствует объединению предложений.  Да и вообще предложение такой структуры неудобно читать в одну фонетическую фразу.

Как проверить эту версию? Надо изменить структуру. Нужна ли запятая  в таком варианте: *В этот миг крышка приподнялась и  рука ухватилась за край*.

**2. Художественная версия**

Историки собрались «ограбить» ночью музей и искали место, где можно спрятаться от охраны, а надоедливый мальчишка им мешал. **Но напугали они его хорошо:**

*Ваня Медведев издал стонущий вздох, попятился, споткнулся о ступеньку, упал, вскочил и опрометью бросился наутек. Бурьин с хохотом выбрался из гробницы и задвинул крышку.*

*— Снова юный поклонник пышных форм? Ему можно только позавидовать — сегодня он узнал массу нового и о женщинах, и о потустороннем мире.*

Художественная задача была как раз в том, чтобы **подчеркнуть последовательность событий** – в этом случае они приобретают м**истический оттенок** в глазах юного вундеркинда.